# RecipientListRouter Configuration

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to configure RecipientListRouter in my Spring-Boot project with the following code:

```
@Bean
public RecipientListRouter locateIncomingCompleteRouter(){
    RecipientListRouter router = new RecipientListRouter();
    router.addRecipient("c1");
    router.addRecipient("c2");
    List<MessageChannel> channels = new ArrayList<MessageChannel>();
    channels.add(c3());
    router.setChannels(channels);
    return router;
}
```

I got following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BeanFactory must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.<init>(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:75) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.getChannelResolver(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:185) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.router.RecipientListRouter.addRecipient(RecipientListRouter.java:161) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

`addRecipients` is intended for dynamically adding recipients after the bean has been created, not during the bean creation itself.

To wire up the recipients with the `@Bean` defintion, use

```
public void setChannels(List<MessageChannel> channels)
```

or

```
public void setRecipients(List<Recipient> recipients)
```

You need references to the actual channels; not just their names.